# How to make displacement to effect all the surface?

Tags: displacement

[image]

[image]

The displacement only working on the side of the woodblock, how to make it on the top of the surface? I have already added subdivision, and still, nothing happens.

Thanks~ :D

Comment: could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: there is the file.  Thanks a lot! :D It is under the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do several things:

- Select your plank and in the *Properties* panel > *Material* tab > *Settings* > *Surface* > *Displacement*, enable *Displacement Only*, otherwise the *Displacement* node won't give anything.

[image]

- Give your plank a *Subdivision Surface* modifier so that it has geometry to move.

[image]

- Switch to Render mode to see the result, apply the scale of your object so that you have a 1/1/1 scaled object, you'll see that it will go crazy because of your settings.

[image]

- So just adjust the settings (didn't try to understand all your nodes organization though).

[image]

Comment: I adjusted the value, the result is not even close to yours. they became rounded. :(